# Drill down table view in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, drilldown

I am using two tableviews in same UIView.When I select an option from one tableview and want to show the sublist on the other tableview(like drill down tableview in iphone).

How could I do that?

Is there any tutorial regarding this?

Comment: Are you trying to add tableViews to window or UIView? If doing on UIWIndow, do instead on UIView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can UINavigationCOntroller to achieve what you you are expecting. UICatalog sample from Apple is a good start.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a master/detail using a UISplitViewController.  You would have a table view in the master and the detail view (with the detailed table view being contextual on what's selected in the master).

Here's a tutorial with UISplitViewController (master/detail):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial

Comment: My app design is little complicated.I couldn't implement it with UIsplitview.Thanks for your reply